# Using colours with bash argument options

Tags: bash, colors

I want to print a string in a particular colour depending on options supplied as
positional arguments.  I will pass a multiline string to tho bash script after the
command line options.

The problem I face is how to print a multiline string.  I am currently using
`printf '%s%s%s\n' "$red" "$@" "$rst"`.  But wouldn't the use of `'%s%s%s\n'`
be a problem when using a multiline string `"$@"` ?

```
local chorn=0 ihorn=0 clk=0 bell=0 syn=0
while (( $# > 0 )); do
 case $1 in
   ("--chorn") chorn=1 ; shift 1 ;;
   ("--ihorn") ihorn=1 ; shift 1 ;;
   ("-c"|"--clacker") clk=1 ; shift 1 ;;
   ("-b"|"--bell") bell=1 ; shift 1 ;;
   ("--") shift 1 ; break ;;
   (*) break ;;
 esac # case ends here
done # while ends here

rst="$( tput sgr0 )"
red="$( tput bold; tput setaf 196 )"
amb="$( tput bold; tput setaf 214 )"

if (( chorn == 1 )); then
  printf '%s%s%s\n' "$red" "$@" "$rst"

elif (( ihorn == 1 )); then
  printf '%s%s%s\n' "$red" "$@" "$rst"

elif (( clk == 1 )); then
  printf '%s%s%s\n' "$amb" "$@" "$rst"

elif (( bell == 1 )); then
  printf '%s%s%s\n' "$amb" "$@" "$rst"
fi
```

Comment: Did you test your code with a multiline string parameter?  Your code works fine on both `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)` and `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: *"would't (it) be a problem?"* Try it (-;! Good luck.

Comment: The `printf` call  works as expected.  Had seen some time ago that `%s%s%s\n` applies to three strings and if there are more strings the `printf` commands will repeat the format.  Could this make problems?  As I do not know what users might put in `"$@"`.  But I think that the double quotes would interpret all function arguments as a single string, meaning that `%s%s%s\n` is what in needed for the colour settings and the multiline string.

Comment: Just curious, is your script intended for hearing-impaired?

Comment: Wondering why you might not use a single variable (visual) with different values (i.e. c,i,k,b), and use a simplified case statement to set the color string (clr_str), then use only one shared output command,  i.e.  printf '%s%s%s\n' "${clr_str}" "$@" "$rst"  .  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the **$@** is contained in **double quotes**, the shell will only see that *as a single string*, as per your quotes definition. Hence, only need 3 x **%s**.